# I/O Error Exception Handling: Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Tags: java, command-line, error-handling, io, arguments

I'm currently working on an assignment (Java) for school. In the instructions/rubric, I'm told that I need to use I/O Exception Handling for command line arguments and other things.

**What The Program Needs to do: **

Take two command line arguments when it runs, or else throw an error. 
The rubric includes this requirement : "I/O error handling is done if no command arguments"

The problem is, every time I try to use an I/O exception catch, I receive this error:

**"Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"**

The quick fix suggestions I get from Eclipse:
1. Remove Catch clause
2. Replace Catch clause with close

**Here is my Code:**

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DecipherText {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        String firstArg;
        String secondArg;

        if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                firstArg = args[0];
                secondArg = args[1];
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Usage Error: Not enough Arguments");
                System.out.println(e);
                return;
            }
        }

        String inputFile = args[0];
        String outputFile = args[1];
    }

    public static boolean receiver() { 
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean output() { // Outputs The Final File
        return false;
    }
}
```

My question(s) are:

1. If so, what am I doing wrong?
2. Is this requirement impossible/asking for the wrong usage of the I/O Error exception handling?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Sully

Comment: Are the arguments to your program file names?

Comment: Yes, because I will be reading text files and writing text files. So with my updated code, (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in use), It works great using the args, "ciphers.txt plain.txt" and runs fine. :)

Comment: yeah.. I feel your teacher meant that you would need to handle IOException while reading/writing to files - ciphers.txt plain.txt

Comment: I'm coming to that conclusion as well based off of these answers. Just wanted to make sure that I wasn't jeopardizing possible points on my assignment :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that Java will never throw an IOException in the code

```
firstArg = args[0];
secondArg = args[1];
```

therefore, there is no need to catch an IOException. An exception you might catch could be ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the user didn't provide 2 arguments.

IOException is sometimes thrown when you're communicating with outside sources such as through a Socket, or reading from a File and some reading of input goes wrong. But determining what's in the args array does not throw an IOException.

I'm not quite sure why your teacher specified I/O Exception. Does he mean input output in general or the Java IOException?

Comment: Well, it says on the rubric: "I/O error handling is done if no command arguments".   It very well could be that I don't even need to throw an actual IOException. It also has another req, "I/O error handling is done if files cannot be opened".     I think I'll be fine if I just throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.   Thanks very much, accepting answers as soon as I am allowed to.

Answer (score 2):

the reason its saying that is because there isn't any operation going on inside the try block that can possible throw IOException. in other words, there's no way you can get IOException from what's inside your try block. You can try catching ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException since that can potentially happen in which case also remove the if(args.length > 0) as its no longer needed since you will be catching that error and handling it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Just about the same as the answer above. All input is greatly appreciated :)         P.S. Thanks for the quality detail

Answer (score 1):

You could use just this code in case theres no IOException, it will stop error, it just wont give an IO if there is one.

```
try {

} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you for listening and editing. Answers that show little more than a code block tend to get flagged by the system, which means it shows up in review queues. That's how I saw this answer.